# How to add the bands value from CSV file to Image Collection for Classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, classification, multi-band, random-forest

I am currently working with GEDI data and Random Forest Classification in Google Earth Engine. I have a csv file which contains 42 bands and about 3600 points. My aim is to import this csv into GEE and do the Random Forest Classification and then take the regression map. The problem happened when I tried to run the regression map by **ee.Image.classify** and error occured *Regression: Layer error: Image.select: Pattern 'Blue' did not match any bands.*. How could I add the bands value from CSV file to the Image Collection to avoid this error and run the code?
My code is as follow:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-vietfix14/assets/GEDIdatapoints1");
var training = table.distinct('system:index');
// AOI 
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-53.727841320713424, 5.4107641852798425],
      [-53.727841320713424, 2.605426055652731],
      [-51.640438976963424, 2.605426055652731],
      [-51.640438976963424, 5.4107641852798425]]], null, false).buffer(1e4);
var heightBand = 'rh99'

Map.addLayer(table)
Map.centerObject(aoi, 12)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var filter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(aoi),
  ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2021-01-01')

  )
var S2composite = ee.ImageCollection(
    ee.Join.saveFirst('cloudProbability').apply({
        primary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filter(filter),
        secondary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY').filter(filter),
        condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
    })
  ).map(function (image) {
  var cloudFree = ee.Image(image.get('cloudProbability')).lt(30)
  return image.updateMask(cloudFree).divide(10000)
  })


var bands =['Blue','Green','Red','NIR','SWIR1','SWIR2','NDVI','EVI','NDWI','MSAVI','SAVI','GNDVI','CVI','DVI','NDMI','GRVI','MSR','GSAVI','GARI','GLI','NDGI','NBR','NDII','SWIR1_Ratio_SWIR2','NIR_Ratio_SWIR1', 'RVI','VVdb','VHdb','ratio_VV_VH','RVIpal','HVdb','HHdb','ratio_HV_HH'];
var S2_composite = S2composite.median();
print(S2_composite)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Train a random forest classifier for regression 
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50)
  .setOutputMode('REGRESSION')
  .train({
    features: training, 
    classProperty: heightBand,
    inputProperties: bands
    });
print(classifier)
var regression = S2_composite.select(bands).classify(classifier, 'predicted').clip(aoi);
// Load and define a continuous palette
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes');

// Choose and define a palette
var palette = palettes.colorbrewer.YlGn[5];
var viz = {palette: palette, min: 0,max:60};
Map.addLayer(regression, viz, 'Regression');
```

My code link: [https://code.earthengine.google.com/14825f7350139a75d1f02796e3c817a3]

My table: [https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-vietfix14/assets/GEDIdatapoints1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you're trying to classify must contain the same bands as the training data used when training the classifier. It doesn't. You have to rename the bands include the indexes in your composite. This should give you an idea, using only a subset of your bands (to same me some time, you'll have to complete this yourself):

```
var S2composite = ee.ImageCollection(
    ee.Join.saveFirst('cloudProbability')
      .apply({
          primary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filter(filter),
          secondary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY').filter(filter),
          condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
      })
    )
    .select(
      ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'],
      ['Blue','Green','Red', 'NIR']
    )
    .map(function (image) {
      var cloudFree = ee.Image(image.get('cloudProbability')).lt(30)
      var indexes = ee.Image([
        image.normalizedDifference(['Red', 'NIR']).rename('NDVI')
    ])
    return image
      .addBands(indexes)
      .updateMask(cloudFree).divide(10000)
    })


var bands = ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'NDVI']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a question that If I select these bands of the image and rename them, it would be the same value with my csv bands at each datapoints, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. The renamed band values must match the names in your training data.

Comment: I means: The NDVI band in CSV file would be the same value as the NDVI created in the image collection at each datapoints?

Comment: The training data is there to give the classifier examples of which values gives which class. Once the classifier is trained, it simply applies what it learned to the image. So, no, the values in your training data doesn't have to mach the image you're classifying. You just need to have the same bands.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I concern about.